# Removing <table> standard line break

Tags: html, css

currently when the code is:

```
<input type=button value="hey">
<table><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>
```

it looks kinda like this:

```
|hey|
+-----+
|hello|
+-----+
```

and I want it to be like this:

```
|hey|+-----+
     |hello|
     +-----+
```

Probably due to the standard/default line break from `<table>`.
Have tried setting the `display:block` attribute from the table in CSS, but without any success.
Any clue how to achieve this :)?

Comment: Just try to add display: inline; to the table

Answer (score 2):

`display:block` will:

- Stop it rendering like a table
- Make it render a line break before and after itself (which tables do by default)

You need `inline-table`, not `block`.

You'll then need to adjust the `vertical-align` of the table and/or button since you want their tops to align instead of their bottoms.

Answer (score 0):

Default a `<table>` is a block element. You need to change the default style of your table with an inline style.

```html
<input type=button value="hey">
<table style="display:inline;"><tr><td>hello</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `display:inline` CSS for `<table>`. It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disply:inline-flex` css property in `<table>`